# Fetch multiple Ids from cookie, and put them in string List

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I'm doing "add product to cart" by putting `Product.Id` into a single cookie via `data-id="@item.ID` from a `foreach` loop and putting it in cookie by doing:

```
if ($.cookie("AddedProductId") != null) {
    var previousValues = $.cookie("AddedProductId");
    $.cookie("AddedProductId", previousValues + ' ' + $(this).data('id'));
} else {
    $.cookie("AddedProductId", $(this).data('id'));
}
```

This is an example of result(*after adding several product*) when I read the cookie via `ViewBag` to View.

> 876d3a7e-8a63-4ed0-82b1-b43907c665ac%2074f766a7-b18e-44ac-83c8-830249916cb4%20ecad2e9c-5cd4-4fcd-8a42-afc8cf8f56d8%20c9733cbd-c5fa-4fc2-b7de-8a02d8f3d5a5

So I can see there's a "`%`" sign between each Guid-Ids. How can I fetch them apart inside the controller and then put each of them in a string-List that I can later work with for db?

Comment: Use [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @StephenMuecke It worked, thank you.